# Restrictions on Function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Under what conditions on '$a$' and '$b$' will the function: $g(x)= af(x)+b$ be concave if $f(x)$ is a concave function?

Will it be by proving the second derivative is less than $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: $a\ge 0$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$.

$\underline{\textbf{Proof}}$:

We suppose $f$ is concave on $I$ and $x_1,x_2\in I$, $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$.
Since $f$ is concave, $$f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2)\geq \lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda) f(x_2)\iff$$
$$f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2)+b\geq \lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda) f(x_2)+b\iff$$

> Multiplying both side by $a$ should preserve the inequality therefore $a$ must be positive then:

$$af(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2)+b\geq  \lambda af(x_1)+(1-\lambda)a f(x_2)+ \lambda b+ (1-\lambda)b\iff$$

$$af(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2)+b\geq  \lambda af(x_1)+b+(1-\lambda)(a f(x_2)+b) \iff$$
 $$g(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2)\geq \lambda g(x_1)+(1-\lambda) g(x_2)$$ thus $g$ is concave.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The concavity is measured by the second derivative of the function, clearly to preserve the same concavity in $g(x)$ as that in $f(x)$, sign of $g''(x)$ must equal sign of $f''(x)$ which is why $a\ge 0$ and there's no restriction on $b$ except that it belongs to the real number set denoted $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Only if the second derivatives of $f,g$ exist, which is not necessarily true.